# Cannot type in text input in IE

Tags: html, input, internet-explorer

I've been searching around for an answer to this one and I can't seem to find the solution.  When I mock-up a simple HTML page with a single text input on it, I'm not able to type in it in IE6 or IE7. The HTML below is exactly what I'm testing this on.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Input Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text">     
    </body>
</html>
```

Has anyone run across this before?  I've tried various DOCTYPE declarations to try and fix the problem and they don't seem to do the trick.  Maybe I haven't tried the right one yet...  A side-note:  I'm testing this running [multipleIEs](http://multipleies.en.softonic.com/) on XP running in Fusion on OS X. (that was a mouthful...)

Comment: that's too emulated to say that there's problem in the html code. the html code definitely should work. but in this case it's not.

Comment: copy/pasted your code - works just fine in IE7

Comment: Alright, so I'll assume for now that it's a problem with where/how they're running.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried this on IE6 (under Windows 7's XP Mode) IE7 and IE8 and it worked in all of them.  Other than a minor point of the input tag not being closed, that is perfectly legal html and it should work in all browsers.

Comment: @Tom: not closing the input tag is perfectly legal HTML, you only need to close it for XHTML. Although nothing is really "legal" without a DOCTYPE ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are testing it using [multipleIEs](http://multipleies.en.softonic.com/) on XP. Installing multiple instances of IE in Windows is known to cause all sorts of problems. IE relies on certain versions of certain DLLs, including IME (Input Method Editors) and others.

Installing multiple versions of IE on the same copy of Windows can and has lead to all sorts of "interesting" problems.

I'd suggest you try the same test with a copy of Windows with only a single version of IE installed. It may be inconvenient, but you would be better off using the [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en).

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is Multiple IEs on XP.. they have a problem, which makes them close to useless. The VPC is really the only way to properly test IE6 these days. Best bet: Serve the page without any css, place a base stylesheet on it like the one from blueprint css (google it) and away you go!